# I want to subtract Curr_YTD and Prev_YTD and divide it by Prev_YTD. The stored procedure needs correction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure, divide

its a stored procedure taking the sum of columns  now I want to take subtract the values Curr_YTD and Prev_YTD and divide by Prev_YTD.
The stored procedure needs correction.
Kindly let me know if anybody could help with subtract and divide operator.

```
SELECT B.TEAMNAME, B.PRIMARY_CODE, B.HIERARCHY_LEVEL, A.THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD,
                 B.PRODUCT_CODE, B.CHANNEL, B.UNIT,'P' PM_INDICATOR, A.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT,
                 A.LOCATION_CODE, A.GEOGRAPHY_NAME,party_id, A.TRX_QTY1, A.TRX_QTY2, A.TRX_QTY3, A.TRX_QTY4,
                 A.TRX_QTY5,A.TRX_QTY6,A.TRX_QTY7,A.TRX_QTY8,A.TRX_QTY9,A.TRX_QTY10,A.TRX_QTY11,
                 A.TRX_QTY12,A.TRX_QTY13,A.TRX_QTY14,A.TRX_QTY15,A.TRX_QTY16,A.TRX_QTY17,A.TRX_QTY18,
                 A.TRX_QTY19,A.TRX_QTY20,A.TRX_QTY21, A.TRX_QTY22,A.TRX_QTY23,A.TRX_QTY24, 
                 A.TRX_QTY1+ A.TRX_QTY2+ A.TRX_QTY3+ A.TRX_QTY4+A.TRX_QTY5+A.TRX_QTY6+A.TRX_QTY7+A.TRX_QTY8 Curr_YTD,
                 A.TRX_QTY13+A.TRX_QTY14+A.TRX_QTY15+A.TRX_QTY16+A.TRX_QTY17+A.TRX_QTY18+A.TRX_QTY19+A.TRX_QTY20 Prev_YTD,
                 (Curr_YTD Minus Prev_YTD)/Prev_YTD  YTD


  FROM (SELECT TTP.LILLY_MARKET_ID THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD,
               TO_DATE(XPS.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT, 'MM / DD / YYYY') PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT,
              TTP.PRIMARY_CD PRIMARY_CODE,
               TLP.LOCATION_CODE,
               RTRIM(TLP.Geography_name) GEOGRAPHY_NAME,
               ttp.party_id,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY1) TRX_QTY1,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY2) TRX_QTY2,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY3) TRX_QTY3,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY4) TRX_QTY4,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY5) TRX_QTY5,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY6) TRX_QTY6,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY7) TRX_QTY7,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY8) TRX_QTY8,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY9) TRX_QTY9,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY10) TRX_QTY10,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY11) TRX_QTY11,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY12) TRX_QTY12,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY13) TRX_QTY13,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY14) TRX_QTY14,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY15) TRX_QTY15,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY16) TRX_QTY16,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY17) TRX_QTY17,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY18) TRX_QTY18,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY19) TRX_QTY19,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY20) TRX_QTY20,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY21) TRX_QTY21,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY22) TRX_QTY22,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY23) TRX_QTY23,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY24) TRX_QTY24
          FROM T_SALECRDTNG_XPS_48861  XPS,
               T_SALECRDTNG_TTP_49354 TTP,
               T_SALESCRD_LOCTNMAPNG  TLP
         WHERE TTP.PARTY_ID = XPS.PRFSNL_ID
           AND TTP.LILLY_MARKET_ID = XPS.LLY_THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD
           AND TLP.MAPPINGID = 48871
           and TLP.PRIMARY_CODE = 'USUA'
           AND XPS.PRODUCT_ID IN ('10210','10215')
           AND XPS.LLY_PRODUCT_ID IN ('203825','208142')
           AND TLP.LOCATION_CODE = TRIM(TTP.MASTER_GEO_ID)
           AND TTP.PRIMARY_CD = TLP.PRIMARY_CODE
          group by TTP.LILLY_MARKET_ID,
                  TTP.PRIMARY_CD,
                  TO_DATE(XPS.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT, 'MM / DD / YYYY'),
                  TLP.LOCATION_CODE,
                  ttp.party_id,
                  TLP.Geography_name) A,
       (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(SC.TEAMNAME) TEAMNAME,
                        DECODE(SC.HIERARCHY_LEVEL, 'TERRITORY',  3,  'DISTRICT', 2, 'AREA', 1, 'REGION', 
                               6,'DIVISION',0, NULL) HIERARCHY_LEVEL,
                        SC.PRODUCT_CODE PRODUCT_CODE,
                        SC.PRIMARY_CODE PRIMARY_CODE,
                        SC.CHANNEL CHANNEL,
                        SC.UNIT UNIT
          FROM T_SALESCRDNG_CONFIG SC
         WHERE SC.CONFIGID = 48994
           AND SC.PRIMARY_CODE = 'USUA'
           AND SC.PRODUCT_CODE = 'CIALIS TOTAL') B
WHERE A.PRIMARY_CODE = B.PRIMARY_CODE
;
```

Comment: Check [LAG and LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `SELCET` and make your existing query a sub-query, something like this

```
SELECT rs.TEAMNAME, rs.PRIMARY_CODE, rs.HIERARCHY_LEVEL, rs.THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD,
                 rs.PRODUCT_CODE, rs.CHANNEL, rs.UNIT,rs.PM_INDICATOR, rs.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT,
                 rs.LOCATION_CODE, rs.GEOGRAPHY_NAME,rs.party_id, rs.TRX_QTY1, rs.TRX_QTY2, rs.TRX_QTY3, rs.TRX_QTY4,
                 rs.TRX_QTY5,rs.TRX_QTY6,rs.TRX_QTY7,rs.TRX_QTY8,rs.TRX_QTY9,rs.TRX_QTY10,rs.TRX_QTY11,
                 rs.TRX_QTY12,rs.TRX_QTY13,rs.TRX_QTY14,rs.TRX_QTY15,rs.TRX_QTY16,rs.TRX_QTY17,rs.TRX_QTY18,
                 rs.TRX_QTY19,rs.TRX_QTY20,rs.TRX_QTY21, rs.TRX_QTY22,rs.TRX_QTY23,rs.TRX_QTY24, 
                 rs.Curr_YTD, rs.Prev_YTD,
                 (rs.Curr_YTD - rs.Prev_YTD)/rs.Prev_YTD  YTD
FROM
(
SELECT B.TEAMNAME, B.PRIMARY_CODE, B.HIERARCHY_LEVEL, A.THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD,
                 B.PRODUCT_CODE, B.CHANNEL, B.UNIT,'P' PM_INDICATOR, A.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT,
                 A.LOCATION_CODE, A.GEOGRAPHY_NAME,party_id, A.TRX_QTY1, A.TRX_QTY2, A.TRX_QTY3, A.TRX_QTY4,
                 A.TRX_QTY5,A.TRX_QTY6,A.TRX_QTY7,A.TRX_QTY8,A.TRX_QTY9,A.TRX_QTY10,A.TRX_QTY11,
                 A.TRX_QTY12,A.TRX_QTY13,A.TRX_QTY14,A.TRX_QTY15,A.TRX_QTY16,A.TRX_QTY17,A.TRX_QTY18,
                 A.TRX_QTY19,A.TRX_QTY20,A.TRX_QTY21, A.TRX_QTY22,A.TRX_QTY23,A.TRX_QTY24, 
                 A.TRX_QTY1+ A.TRX_QTY2+ A.TRX_QTY3+ A.TRX_QTY4+A.TRX_QTY5+A.TRX_QTY6+A.TRX_QTY7+A.TRX_QTY8 Curr_YTD,
                 A.TRX_QTY13+A.TRX_QTY14+A.TRX_QTY15+A.TRX_QTY16+A.TRX_QTY17+A.TRX_QTY18+A.TRX_QTY19+A.TRX_QTY20 Prev_YTD
  FROM (SELECT TTP.LILLY_MARKET_ID THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD,
               TO_DATE(XPS.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT, 'MM / DD / YYYY') PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT,
              TTP.PRIMARY_CD PRIMARY_CODE,
               TLP.LOCATION_CODE,
               RTRIM(TLP.Geography_name) GEOGRAPHY_NAME,
               ttp.party_id,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY1) TRX_QTY1,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY2) TRX_QTY2,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY3) TRX_QTY3,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY4) TRX_QTY4,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY5) TRX_QTY5,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY6) TRX_QTY6,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY7) TRX_QTY7,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY8) TRX_QTY8,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY9) TRX_QTY9,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY10) TRX_QTY10,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY11) TRX_QTY11,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY12) TRX_QTY12,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY13) TRX_QTY13,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY14) TRX_QTY14,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY15) TRX_QTY15,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY16) TRX_QTY16,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY17) TRX_QTY17,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY18) TRX_QTY18,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY19) TRX_QTY19,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY20) TRX_QTY20,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY21) TRX_QTY21,
               SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY22) TRX_QTY22,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY23) TRX_QTY23,SUM(XPS.TRX_QTY24) TRX_QTY24
          FROM T_SALECRDTNG_XPS_48861  XPS,
               T_SALECRDTNG_TTP_49354 TTP,
               T_SALESCRD_LOCTNMAPNG  TLP
         WHERE TTP.PARTY_ID = XPS.PRFSNL_ID
           AND TTP.LILLY_MARKET_ID = XPS.LLY_THERAPEUTICCLASS_CD
           AND TLP.MAPPINGID = 48871
           and TLP.PRIMARY_CODE = 'USUA'
           AND XPS.PRODUCT_ID IN ('10210','10215')
           AND XPS.LLY_PRODUCT_ID IN ('203825','208142')
           AND TLP.LOCATION_CODE = TRIM(TTP.MASTER_GEO_ID)
           AND TTP.PRIMARY_CD = TLP.PRIMARY_CODE
          group by TTP.LILLY_MARKET_ID,
                  TTP.PRIMARY_CD,
                  TO_DATE(XPS.PROCESSINGPERIOD_DT, 'MM / DD / YYYY'),
                  TLP.LOCATION_CODE,
                  ttp.party_id,
                  TLP.Geography_name) A,
       (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(SC.TEAMNAME) TEAMNAME,
                        DECODE(SC.HIERARCHY_LEVEL, 'TERRITORY',  3,  'DISTRICT', 2, 'AREA', 1, 'REGION', 
                               6,'DIVISION',0, NULL) HIERARCHY_LEVEL,
                        SC.PRODUCT_CODE PRODUCT_CODE,
                        SC.PRIMARY_CODE PRIMARY_CODE,
                        SC.CHANNEL CHANNEL,
                        SC.UNIT UNIT
          FROM T_SALESCRDNG_CONFIG SC
         WHERE SC.CONFIGID = 48994
           AND SC.PRIMARY_CODE = 'USUA'
           AND SC.PRODUCT_CODE = 'CIALIS TOTAL') B
WHERE A.PRIMARY_CODE = B.PRIMARY_CODE
) rs
;
```

Comment: Hi Thakur, good to learn that the solution worked for you. Can you please accept this as the answer?